# EC2 Public DNS changed but Nginx reverse proxy still works

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns, nginx-reverse-proxy

This is the scenario:

- EC2 instance1 that stores and serves `example.com`
- EC2 instance2 that stores and serves `subdomain.example.com`

So, every time that instance1 receives an HTTP request for `subdomain.example.com` it redirects it to instance2. Instance1 has attached an Elastic IP so the public IP never changes, but with instance2 I was working only with its Public DNS. On my Nginx Server Block (instance1) I redirect http requests to instance2 using its public DNS.

The thing is, I've rebooted (stop/start) my instance2 and its public DNS has changed but the redirection to its "old" public DNS still works and the application is still working properly.

Does anybody know why is this happening? I just want to be sure that everything is okay, don't like surprises...

Comment: I think when you reboot the instance only Public IP changes but not the Public DNS. So the public IP may not match Public DNS.

Comment: Why don't you `dig` the old public DNS and see what happens. The public DNS is constructed from the public IP, so if the public IP changes for instance2 after stop/start, then the public DNS will also change. There is no way the old DNS resolves to instance2. Also, you can check the nginx log of instance2.

Comment: @Asdfg I've checked Public DNS and it changes... as well as the IP.

Comment: @helloV now that you mention it, I cannot see anything in the nginx access log (on instance2), is that occurring because all the traffic is being received first in instance1 (reverse proxy) and then redirected to instance2? I thought even though the traffic goes first to instance1 when it redirects it I could see the logs on my instance2...

Answer (score 1):

I think its due to the TTL delay in DNS propagation. After sometime you won't see it working.

Comment: Yeah, I believe this is the only feasible reason.